# Troubles with HTML-tags in post content in octobercms frontend

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms

I'm trying to display my terms' content on the page using component 'TermsDescription'. 
I try this code on my page :

<...>  **{% component 'TermsDescription' %}** <...>  **{% component 'TermsDescription|raw' %}** <...>

But display same as screen-shot [image]

my content is  displayed with  <.p> tag. So, tags displayed as text, not as HTML-tags at all. I have either 'only text' without decoration, or pure tags-as-a-text on the page. What am I missing? Where is the solution? :)

Comment: Can you please show your components/termsdescription/default.htm file?

you need to display raw on whatever's in the TermsDescription component

Comment: @julianpitt [builderDetails TermsDescription]
modelClass = "MyCompany\Project\Models\Popup"
identifierValue = 1
modelKeyColumn = "id"
displayColumn = "popup_description"
notFoundMessage = "Record not found" 
==


{% component  'TermsDescription'  %}

Answer (score 0):

You can not use raw in defining component like this `{% component 'TermsDescription|raw' %}`.

Instead of this, you should have to understand the components in **OctoberCMS**.

Suppose you are passing data from your **TermsDescription** component.

```
    $this->page['data']= /Data::find($id);
```

And it contains **title** and **description**. And  **Description** has data as seen in your question.

Then you can do this way
 `{{ data.description|raw' }}` where you want to print description.